# Django: How to keep non-PII from removed users under GDPR

Tags: django

I'm using Django to build a B2B SaaS hobby project, where each company (tenant) can have many users and, eventually, remove them.

It's important to keep the reason why a user was removed.

The straightfoward way for this to be solved would be to turn `is_active` to False and add a `reason_for_removal` field on the User model. Then make sure `is_active` is indexed (is it by default in Django?) and all querysets are appropriately filtered.

However, in a GDPR world, is this the right way to do it? Does it make sense to create a separate model called `RemovedUser` just with the `user` and `reason_for_removal` fields (and no other Personal Identifiable Information) and delete the original user instance?

Comment: Well if you stick to this, according to GDPR you should clean your backups too... It's impossible, just add to the terms and conditions that you keep their data in your database even if their account is deactivated...

Comment: @ThunderHorn I think that regardless of the GPDR I myself wouldn't want my data to be in some company's systems when I can't benefit from it anymore... But given that removing PII is entirely feasible, what would be the right way to do it? New model or keep the current one (or another method)?